# Gatsby y @reach/router no enruta componentes

Tags: reactjs, router, gatsby

Tengo un page index.jsx el cuál por ejemplo tiene esto

```
const A =()=>(
  <h1>PAGE A</h1>
)
const B =()=>(
  <h1>PAGE B</h1>
)
const IndexPage = () => {
  return (
   <Router>
     <A path="/" />
     <B path="b" />
   </Router>
  )
}
```

En un proyecto de React normal con webpack si ingresas a "sitio-web.com/b"
debería salirte el componente B, pero en Gatsby me sale que la página no existe, evidentemente si agrego el componente B como un archivo independiente como "B.js" en el directorio de "pages" si funciona, pero para eso no necesito "@reach/router". No sé si estoy equivocado en algo, o si debo configurar algo en gatsby-config.js.

Gracias de ante mano por su respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Para fines prácticos te recomiendo utilizar Gatsby para generar tus páginas automáticamente en la carpeta `pages` y @reach/router para navegar entre estas, si es que lo utilizarás sus funciones más avanzadas, como manejo de variables, props, enrutamiemtos automáticos, los hooks que tiene, en eso te facilita mucho el trabajo, más que la API incluida en Gatsby, pero si solamente vas a utilizar el componente `Link` para mostrar un componente u otro, o ir de una página a otra sin funciones, props, condicionales, o cosas más avanzadas, si quédate con la API nativa de Gatsby, no es necesario incluir alguna otra librería